# Python: How can I get Firefox preferences to automatically download a .eml file?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium-webdriver, preference, eml

I am trying to set the preferences on my Firefox browser to never ask to save to disk when downloading a .eml file (I want Firefox to automatically download the EML file).

```
def setUp(self):
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Downloads\\"))
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/csv,message/rfc822')
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
self.base_url = baseurl
self.verificationErrors = []
self.accept_next_alert = True
self.driver.implicitly_wait(3)
```

With this code I am able to download a .csv without having the saveToDisk pop-up appear in Firefox, however this will not work with .eml despite having the 'message/rfc822' MIME-type set.

Can any help explain if there is something I am missing in order to download .eml's without having any pop-ups be displayed in Firefox?

Comment: try `wget url\sample.eml` (or use browser Network tab in F12) directly and see the `Content-Type` header. Some times, server sends `application/octet-stream` which means server also does not know the type.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem and sloved it with this:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', os.getcwd())
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/xml,text/plain,text/xml,image/jpeg,text/eml");        
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```